# Laravel 4 - PHP-FFMpeg - progress

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using PHP-FFmpeg with laravel to create encodes of the clips uploaded to the app ([php-ffmpeg github](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)). The documentation says that transcoding progress can be monitored in realtime, by providing the 'progress' event callback.

```
$video  = $ffmpeg->open($originaldir);

$format = new $format_class();

$format->on('progress', function ($video, $format, $percentage) {
            echo("$percentage % transcoded");
});
```

The function is written in the controller but, how can I get the the **$percentage** variable out of the closure and show it in the view?

**Update**

I have tried to use this package to store the **$percentage** var into a js variable, so I could access it in the view: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I've tried to do in the controller:

```
JavaScript::put([
    'prog' => $percentage
]);
```

Comment: You can pass variables to the view like this:

`View::make('myView')->with('percentage', $percentage);`

Comment: I have tried to do it this way, and also with the compact() method. I am trying to get the data with blade if statement but it doesn't seem to work. I think the best way has been suggested..

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact code you've tried in your Blade template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to store the percentage somewhere - the user's session, in a database of some sort, etc. - and retrieve the value periodically via AJAX to display to the user.

Comment: can you provide an example?